# Is there a way to extract text from PostScript (.ps , .eps) files using Java?

Tags: java, postscript, text-extraction

I am looking for a solution similiar to PDFBox for PDFs of Apache Tika, however, for PS files.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like James Black says, it's probably best just to convert to PDF and use your familiar tools.

However, there does exist [pstotext](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/pstotext.htm) which is available in, e.g., the Ubuntu universe in its own package.

Ghostscript itself also comes with both ps2txt and ps2ascii which can also do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ghostscript to convert to a pdf, http://www.osalt.com/ghostscript, then there are various libraries to handle a pdf.

This has an advantage in that you are only pulling from PDFs, so you can handle other formats as long as you can convert them to PDFs.